# This code work in local development system and local IIS but not working fine in Application server

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Why is this code not working in my production server? This code is correctly working in local development system. Do I need to change any settings in my production server?

```
$(function() {  
  alert('working fine');

  $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    var con = $.connection.hitCount;
    var message = 'hai';
    var name = 'suresh';

    con.client.onHitRecorded = function(i) { 
        alert('not working'); // not firing
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {

        con.server.send(message, name);
        alert('working fine');

    });
})
```

Comment: Please describe "not working fine". Do you have any error? Is there any message in the console ? Using an http debugger (like fiddler), do you see any clue ?

Comment: All the script is working good but     con.client.onHitRecorded = function(i) { 
        alert('not working'); // not firing
    };  not firing this method

Comment: debugger is not going to con.client.onHitRecorded function, but i didn't get any error. The functionality is not working fine because of client method is not calling but server method is working fine

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem in code. actually this is not a code error. If you want solve this add redis dll to your application. if you add this it will work fine.